# CSS3 animation with keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I make a css3 animation with key frames. But i have a problem. This is my code:

```
a[title*="in je favorieten"]:hover {
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 3;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
    from {
        width: 25px;
    }

    to {
        width: 80px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein  {
    from {
        width: 25px;
    }

    to {
        width: 80px;
    }
}
```

The problem is. When i hover the a element. The a element must be set to width 80. When i hover out. Than the a element must be return to 25 width. But now, i hover and he does the animation. And than he return to 25. How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not a good idea to be implemented via animations ,

Try using CSS3 transitions [support is the same ]

Here is the sample code

```
a{ 

 display:inline-block;
 width:25px;
 -moz-transition: width 1s; // Mozzilla
 -webkit-transition: width 1s; // Webkit
 transition: width 1s; // W3C
}

a:hover{
 // with a simple trickary this can be used to generate the same results what you want.
  width:100px;
}
```

And if u still want to follow the animation thing

Just add a rule saying

```
 a[title*="in je favorieten"]{
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-name: slideout;
-webkit-animation-name: slideout;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 3;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
-moz-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
 }


 @-moz-keyframes slideout {
    from {
        width: 80px;
     }

     to {
        width: 25px;
     }
   }

@-webkit-keyframes slideout  {
    from {
        width: 80px;
     }

    to  {
       width: 25px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer that i search for

Answer (score 1):

except that approach is not correct either... **you should stick to transition as Abhishek wrote at first.**

For CSS3 animations with keyframes you should check the specs. What your code basically says is "do the animation specified in 'slidein'/'slideout' 3 times in a row with alternating direction (left to right / right to left)".

Remove the following 3 lines and include Abhishek's code to make it work (better)

```
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 3;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
-moz-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
```

though this might still cause the layer to flicker from being shown to being not shown upon loading the page (did not test that)

reference:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-iteration-count